# Why Windows 10 installation does not start in Virtual Box?

Tags: windows-10

I tried installing Windows 10 in Virtual Box. 
Installation won't start. 
Appears only Windows 10 logo.

Answer (score 0):

There are known problems with VirtualBox and Windows 10. As per [the download site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads): "Please be aware that Windows 10 is not yet officially supported! There are known problems with VirtualBox 5.0.2 on Windows 10 hosts and with Windows 10 guests. Some of the problems are fixed in the most recent test build which can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds)."

Furthermore, there are forum threads about the different issues with VB and Windows 10: [The release version of Windows 10](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68590&start=345&sid=a81fdcace4f2e1690de3a503d96ae377) and [the Preview version of Windows 10](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=69672&start=30).

The reasons for the problems is not yet fully determined, but the test builds seem to have solved some of the problems. However, new Windows 10 patches may break those temporary fixes. Also note that VirtualBox seem not to be alone of having compatibility problems with this brand new version of Windows.